# CSS "color" vs. "font-color"

Tags: css

Anyone know why CSS provides `color` for text, but does not have `font-color` or `text-color`?

Seems very counter-intuitive, kind of like `text-decoration: underline` rather than `font-style` or something related to fonts.

Does anyone know why/how the W3C came up with such a wide array of CSS names like this?

Comment: I have started a petion to introduce the "font-color" property. Maybe some of you would like to sign it.
https://www.change.org/p/world-wide-web-consortium-introduce-the-font-color-css-property?recruiter=238928026&utm_source=share_for_starters&utm_medium=copyLink

Comment: You can do it within the <font> tag.  e.g. <font color="red">Hello World!<font>

Comment: @airider74 What year are you living in? The <font> element has been deprecated for many years.

Comment: Yes it has ... but it still works

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I would think that one reason could be that the color is applied to things other than font.  For example:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    color: red;
}
```

Yields both a red font color and a red border.

Alternatively, it could just be that the W3C's CSS standards are completely backwards and nonsensical as evidenced elsewhere.

Comment: Try adding the following to the CSS on this page: `.post-text {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid red;
}` You'll see that the text color is blue even though the border color is red.

Comment: then by definition, font-color is faster then color as it has to do less work.

Answer (score 196):

The same way Boston came up with its street plan. They followed the cow paths already there, and built houses where the streets weren't, and after a while it was too much trouble to change.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old post but as MisterZimbu stated, the `color` property is defining the values of other properties, as the `border-color` and, with CSS3, of `currentColor`.

`currentColor` is very handy if you want to use the font color for other elements (as the background or custom checkboxes and radios of inner elements for example).

Example:

```css
.element {
  color: green;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.innerElement1 {
  border: solid 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.innerElement2 {
  background: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="innerElement1"></div>
  <div class="innerElement2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this gives even more reason to have a separate `font-color`/`text-color` property available. That way you can have many parts of the element with one particular default colour, and the text in another if you want. Otherwise it ties the default colour to the text colour.

Comment: @BenJ Binding the default colour to the main colour was probably the intention in the early days of the web. Today you can use css variables (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and/or use a css preprocessor as Sass, Less, Stylus, etc. where it's easy to work with variables.