# Adding css styles to specific element and a link in the same time

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have two css classes as below.

```
.disabled {
    font-color: #ccc;
  }

  .grayout {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  }
```

And I used them in following jquery code.

```
 $('#priority_choices li:first-child .move_up').addClass("disabled grayout");
```

This is how the link displayed after applying the css styles
[image: This is how the link displayed after applying the css styles]

I need to apply some other styles to it to change the colors. But when I apply `font-color : #ddd;` only the color or arrow getting changed.
I inspect the code and the styles are applying to the word as below in a common file. So this style is applying to all the a.iconic_link span of application.

```
a.iconic_link span {
    color: #003399;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

How could I change the color #003399 only for that element.

**Edited**

This is the html code which used with ruby on rails.

```
<%= form_tag respond_round_path(round), :remote => true do %>
    <ul id="priority_choices">
      <% round.item_version.metadata["responses"].each_with_index do |r, i| %>
          <li id="choice_<%= i %>">
            <div class="movers">
              <%= iconic_link_to_function "arrow-up", "Up", "moveUp(#{i})", :class => "move_up", :data_label_up => "Option " +r.gsub('<p>', '').gsub('</p>', '').html_safe + " Move Up Selected", :option_label_up => r.gsub('<p>', '').gsub('</p>', '').html_safe %>
              <%= iconic_link_to_function "arrow-down", "Down", "moveDown(#{i})", :class => "move_down", :data_label_down => "Option "+ r.gsub('<p>', '').gsub('</p>', '').html_safe + " Move Down Selected", :option_label_down => r.gsub('<p>', '').gsub('</p>', '').html_safe %>
            </div>
            <%= r.gsub('<li>', '').gsub('</li>', '<br />').html_safe %>
          </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit response" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "response" %>
<% end %>
```

I am applying the css within below function.

```
function updateButtons() {

        $('#priority_choices li:first-child .move_up').addClass("disabled grayout");

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code to apply css?

Comment: I have function as, updatebuttons(){$('#priority_choices li:first-child .move_up').addClass("disabled grayout");}

Comment: Can you please update the question with that function?

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: It is a ruby on rails code.I will update it in the question

Comment: Since this jQuery code and CSS will run after render, please post the rendered HTML as well since that is the core of this question.

Comment: I have attached the html code also which used with the ruby on rails

Comment: `font-color` does not exist in css. It should be `color`.

Comment: I added $('#priority_choices li:first-child .move_up').css({color: '#ddd'}); within the updatebuttons() function. But the color of Arrow only changed. Color is not changed in word Up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2501723/125981

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.disabled {
    font-color: #ccc;
  }
```

to

```
.disabled {
    color: #ccc;
}
```